# Troubleshooting Live View Count in Flask: Issues with Count Increment and Real-Time Updates

Tags: python, flask

I made some code to try to add a live view count but i have 2 problems, when i go to /view_count and reload the count goes up even tho i only want it to go up when its in / and its not live i need to reload the page and if 2 ppl go on at the same time it sometimes updates sometimes doesnt so i just dont know what to do, sometimes it works locally but when i host it its always messed up

this is my code:

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
view_count = 0



port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    global view_count
    view_count += 1
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/view_count')
def get_view_count():
    return (f"View count: {view_count}")


@app.route('/admin')
def root():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def all_routes(path):
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=port)
```

Comment: This does not seem like the best approach to solve this problem as several issues could arise when hosting. 
Something you could try is to use a database to store the count element which is incremented every time the route is visited. 
This way your view_count doesn't always reset when the server is restarted and I believe this approach would solve all your other issues. I tried it out on my localhost and it works fine but I believe the database would solve your issue with hosting.

Comment: what if i dont want to setup a whole database and read and write for a view_count? i know it will be gone and restart when the server restarts but idc can u just show me how to fix it if u know?

Comment: so like if im hosting it its impossible to have it reliable except with a database? i think its smth to do with the endpoints maybe all of them get triggered IDK if a database is gonna work ill do it but there is no reason for a database to work and a var to not work, the problem is that its incrementing wrong database wont fix that it will just increment wrong in the... database

Comment: i fixed it i just need to remove the 
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def all_routes(path):
    return redirect('/')